# C++ strict aliasing violation

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I have a (char*) buffer. Am I allowed to do as follows:

1. `int8_t i8 = *(int8_t*)buffer;`
2. `int16_t i16 = *(int16_t*)buffer;`
3. `float f = *(float*)buffer;`
4. `int8_t i = 22;  *(int8_t*)buffer = i`
5. `int16_t i = 25;  *(int16_t*)buffer = i`
6. `float f = 16.4;  *(float*)buffer = f`

EDIT:
Let's assume the buffer was created in one of these ways:

1. `char* buffer = new char[300 * sizeof(char)];`
2. `char* buffer = (char*)malloc(300 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: Without knowing what `buffer` points to this question is not answerable.

Comment: @UnholySheep edited. I assume the answer depends on that, whether malloc or new was used ?

Comment: See the comments about [strict aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` the language guarantees that this will always be `1`, on every platform.

Answer (score 2):

For the version with `new` neither of them is guaranteed to not have undefined behavior on all possible implementations:

1. is an aliasing violation (and therefore undefined behavior) if `int8_t` is not `char` or `signed char` (which it however is on all platforms I am aware of). It is also reading an indeterminate value if you don't assign a value to `buffer[0]` inbetween, also causing undefined behavior.
2. is also an aliasing violation if `int16_t` is not `char` or `signed char`, which it can't be on any usual platform with `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Initialization of `buffer[0]` is missing again.
3. is guaranteed to be an aliasing violation.
4. same as 1. minus the indeterminate value issue.
5. same as 2. minus the indeterminate value issue.
6. same as 3.

---

For the version with `malloc` the following holds, assuming you only ever access `buffer` with *only one out of* the types you list:

4., 5., and 6. are all allowed assuming the `sizeof` of the pointed-to type is at most `300`.

1., 2. and 3.: These are allowed under the condition above and assuming you actually write to the buffer in the way that you do in 4., 5. or 6. *with matching type* first.

---

Note that you can remedy the issues in the `new` case with the help of `std::launder` to make it equivalent to the `malloc` case.

Also note that the `malloc` case only works because `malloc` is specified to implicitly create object of implicit lifetime type and return a pointer to a suitable one of these created objects. And all scalar types are implicit lifetime types, meaning all the ones you listed are as well.

It would be much easier not to make a mistake here by using placement-new to create the object(s) you want to store in the buffer explicitly. The placement-new returns a pointer to the newly created object that you can use without any casting.

None of this in any way allows writing to the buffer with one type and then reading with another or writing with different types to the same buffer location. That is always going to be an aliasing violation one way or another if no placement-new or similar intervenes to change the type (and reinitialize the value!). For casting between bit representations of different types use `std::bit_cast` instead. (And maybe `std::start_lifetime_as` in C++23 is also helpful.)

Comment: An additional requirement, so far as I can tell when using storage to hold a new type, is that a compiler be able to statically determine that the lifetime of any object of contrary type that might occupy the storage has *definitely* ended.  In https://godbolt.org/z/P76xx8s1K for example, a compiler looking just as `test` would be unable to statically determine whether lvalue `p3[i]` would read read the object created and assigned with the first placement new operator and lvalue `p1[i]`, or the third placement new operator and lvalue `p3[k]`.

Comment: @supercat Creating a new object in the storage of another object ends the lifetime of the previous object (with the exception of nested objects), so it becomes impossible to read the prior object's value. Pointers are also supposed to be (on the specification level) aware of which object they point to, not only the address. Your code seems to demonstrate a Clang bug. (Also, a `std::launder` after a placement-new is going to do nothing. `new` already returns a pointer to the object of the given type alive at the location and only one such object can be alive)

Comment: Clang and gcc have adopted an abstraction model which is incapable of handling the constructs shown in the above code other than by disabling aliasing analsysis almost completely.  I think the real defect is with the specification's notion that anything should *care* about the object lifetimes in question.  A model where storage which doesn't contain any non-PODS object will simultnaeously contain all PODS that will fit, but that limits the circumstances where objects may be *accessed*, would be easier for humans and compilers to reason about, since it could be amenable to static analysis.

Comment: If, for example, C++ had a rule that said that when a reference is constructed from a `void*` or a pointer of some other type, any storage which is modified during the lifetime *of the reference* must be accessed exclusively via pointers that were at least potentially based upon the reference, or exclusively via pointers that were at least potentially not based upon the reference, and this code had used lifetime-limited references instead of pointers, then it would have been obvious what a compiler would need to do to process the code correctly.